Как залить сайт Blazor на хостинг?

Попытался залить сайт на хостинг, но выводит подобную ошибку. Если честно не совсем понимаю что делать. Может не достает какого-то файла?


Начнем с того, что не надо заливать исходники. Нужно опубликовать приложение хотя бы в папку и скопировать. Так же важно, чтобы хостинг поддерживал asp.net core

ASP на шаред(php)-хостинг? Серьёзно?

@SeVlad будьте добры, можете чуть поподробнее объяснить этот момент? что я фундаментально не так понимаю?

@SeVlad Я так-то новичок. Просто хотелось увидеть как происходит деплой сайта, но как оказалось, для этого рановато... Вам спасибо за объяснение, правда пока что не понимаю многих вещей, но ваш ответ обязательно поможет мне в будущем.

@saidrajabov, Блазор можно на IIS на своем компе локально опубликовать для тестов. С визуал студио публикацию делать в релиз режиме, предварительно создав сайт на IIS. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&utm_source=chatgpt.com&tabs=visual-studio

@SeVlad, для .net не обязательно нужен windows, он вполне и на *nix системах работает

Объясняю: C# - это в первую очередь Windows системы. При выходе .NET появилась возможность разворачивать приложение и под Linux, но чтобы это сделать, вам надо 1. Чтобы хостинг имел такую поддержку (обычно они все настроены только под php). 2. Вы должны правильно собрать проект, именно под Linux. На данный момент, самый простой и доступный способ публикации таких проектов - это аренда VPS/VDS, то есть виртуальную Linux систему, где вы сами, через консоль, ставите нужные пакеты и заргужаете нужные файлы.

Ну что вы сразу, есть шаред хостинги под .Net.
ну и если приложение frontend-only Blazor WebAssembly в теории его можно куда угодно залить хоть на github pages.
но я не думаю, что у автора такой, поэтому про это промолчал.
